# preventing the item to add to the dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

[In addition to this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72053882/group-the-similar-items-in-a-multiple-level-hierarchy)

I want to create a hierarchical list in a 3 level category.

My data are in the following ways:

```
var appCategoryList = new List<AppCategoryDataModel>() {
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 4844, ParentappCategoryId = null , AppCategoryName = "ItemResearch", ProtocolId = 5164, ProtocolTitle="ABC: Evaluation" },
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 4844, ParentappCategoryId = null, AppCategoryName = "ItemResearch", ProtocolId = null, ProtocolTitle=""},
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 4845, ParentappCategoryId = null, AppCategoryName = "ItemHostpital", ProtocolId = null, ProtocolTitle="" },
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 4845, ParentappCategoryId = null, AppCategoryName = "ItemHostpital", ProtocolId =5162 , ProtocolTitle="ABC: 3/28/20" },
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 4845, ParentappCategoryId = null, AppCategoryName = "ItemHostpital", ProtocolId =5164 , ProtocolTitle="ABC: Evaluation" },
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 4845, ParentappCategoryId = null, AppCategoryName = "ItemHostpital", ProtocolId =5165 , ProtocolTitle="ABC: section", },
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 4845, ParentappCategoryId = null, AppCategoryName = "ItemHostpital", ProtocolId =5192 , ProtocolTitle="ABC: 3/31/20", },
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 4846, ParentappCategoryId = null, AppCategoryName = "Contact information", ProtocolId = null, ProtocolTitle="", },
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 4846, ParentappCategoryId = null, AppCategoryName = "Contact information", ProtocolId =5164 , ProtocolTitle="ABC: Evaluation", },
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 4852, ParentappCategoryId = null, AppCategoryName = "UP", ProtocolId =null , ProtocolTitle="", },
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 4852, ParentappCategoryId = null, AppCategoryName = "UP", ProtocolId = 5164, ProtocolTitle="ABC: Evaluation", },
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 5023, ParentappCategoryId = null, AppCategoryName = "Call survival guide", ProtocolId = null, ProtocolTitle="" },
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 5023, ParentappCategoryId = null, AppCategoryName = "Call survival guides", ProtocolId =5164 , ProtocolTitle="ABC: Evaluation" },
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 5085, ParentappCategoryId = null, AppCategoryName = "OE", ProtocolId =null, ProtocolTitle="" },
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 5085, ParentappCategoryId = null, AppCategoryName = "OE", ProtocolId =5164 , ProtocolTitle="ABC: Evaluation" },

   new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 5099, ParentappCategoryId = null, AppCategoryName = "OEM", ProtocolId =null , ProtocolTitle=null },

    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 5334, ParentappCategoryId = 5085, AppCategoryName = "mmkk update", ProtocolId =null , ProtocolTitle= null },
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 5336, ParentappCategoryId = 5085, AppCategoryName = "xdgdrg", ProtocolId =null , ProtocolTitle=null },
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 5348, ParentappCategoryId = 5023, AppCategoryName = "test", ProtocolId =null , ProtocolTitle=null },
    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 5341, ParentappCategoryId = 5023, AppCategoryName = "New Category Level-1", ProtocolId =null , ProtocolTitle= null },

    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 5349, ParentappCategoryId = 5341, AppCategoryName = "New Category Level-2", ProtocolId =null , ProtocolTitle= null },

    new AppCategoryDataModel() { AppCategoryId = 5352, ParentappCategoryId = 5348, AppCategoryName = "New category3", ProtocolId =null , ProtocolTitle= null },



}.OrderBy(ap => ap.AppCategoryName);
```

**AppCategoryDataModel**

```
public class AppCategoryDataModel
{
    public int AppCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int? ParentappCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string AppCategoryName { get; set; }
    public int? ProtocolId { get; set; }
    public string ProtocolTitle { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<int, FirstLevelCategory> dictCategories = new Dictionary<int, FirstLevelCategory>();

foreach (AppCategoryDataModel category in appCategoryList)
{
    if (!dictCategories.ContainsKey(category.AppCategoryId))
    {
        dictCategories.Add(category.AppCategoryId, new FirstLevelCategory()
        {
            AppCategoryId = category.AppCategoryId,
            AppCategoryName = category.AppCategoryName,
            AppCategoryProtocolData = category.ProtocolId != null ?

            new List<ProtocolDetails>() {
                new ProtocolDetails()
                {
                    ProtocolId = (int)category.ProtocolId,
                    ProtocolTitle = category.ProtocolTitle
                }
            } : new List<ProtocolDetails>(),

            SubCategory = category.ParentappCategoryId != null
            ? GetSubCategoryList(appCategoryList, category.AppCategoryId)
            : new List<SecondLevelCategory>()
        });
    }
    else
    {
        if (category.ProtocolId != null)
            dictCategories[category.AppCategoryId].AppCategoryProtocolData.Add(new ProtocolDetails()
            {
                ProtocolId = (int)category.ProtocolId,
                ProtocolTitle = category.ProtocolTitle
            });
    }
}
foreach (var key in dictCategories.Keys.ToList())
{
    dictCategories[key].CategoryProtocolCount = dictCategories[key].AppCategoryProtocolData.Count();
}
```

**FirstLevelCategory**

```
public class FirstLevelCategory
{
    public int AppCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string AppCategoryName { get; set; }
    public bool IsExpand { get; set; }
    public bool IsExpandAll { get; set; }
    public bool IsCategoryHierarchyExpanded { get; set; }
    //count of AppCategoryProtocolData 
    public int CategoryProtocolCount { get; set; }
    public List<SecondLevelCategory> SubCategory { get; set; }
    public List<ProtocolDetails> AppCategoryProtocolData { get; set; }
}
public class ProtocolDetails
{
    public int ProtocolId { get; set; }
    public string ProtocolTitle { get; set; }
}
```

My problem here is the item where `ParentappCategoryId != null` should come as a sub-category, but that has also been added in the first level category. I am not able to filter that properly.

How should I prevent the item that has ParentAppCategory to be added in the first.

SecondLevelCategory

```
public class SecondLevelCategory
{
    public int AppCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string AppCategoryName { get; set; }
    public bool? ToggleSubCategory { get; set; }
    public bool IsExpand { get; set; }
    public int subcategoryProtocolCount { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ProtocolDetails> SubCategoryProtocolData { get; set; }
    public List<ThirdLevelCategory> ThirdLevelCategory { get; set; }
}
```

ThirdLevelCategory

```
 public class ThirdLevelCategory
 {
    public int AppCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string AppCategoryName { get; set; }
    public bool? ToggleThirdLevelCategory { get; set; }
    public int? ThirdLevelCategoryProtocolCount { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProtocolDetails> ThirdLevelCategoryProtocolData { get; set; }
 }
```

Expected Result:

```
   ItemResearch
        ABC: Evaluation
    ItemHostpital
        ABC: 3/28/20
        ABC: Evaluation
        ABC: section
        ABC: 3/31/20
    Contact information
        ABC: Evaluation
    UP
        ABC: Evaluation
    OE
        ABC: Evaluation
            mmkk update --subcategory
            xdgdrg      --subcategory
    Call survival guides
        ABC: Evaluation --details
            test  --subcategory
                New category3 --thirdcategory
            New Category Level-1 --subcategory
                New Category Level-2 -- thirdcategory
```

Comment: Please can you boil it down to an actual question? There maybe a question hidden between the wall of code but i doubt you will find many people to scan all of this to still read between the lines what your problem is. And at best reduce the code to the minimum needed to understand that question then.

Comment: item where ParentappCategoryId != null should come as a sub-category but it is also added in the first level category, my problem here is how would i prevent that with the use case scenario i have.

Comment: So you basically want to to stop dictCategories from containing items where ParentappCategoryId is null? That way any where it's not null will reference something that's not classed a first level category.

Comment: no items where ParentappCategoryId is null should be on dicCategories but items with parentappcategoryid should be on subcategory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem here is the item where ParentappCategoryId != null should come as a sub-category, but that has also been added in the first level category. I am not able to filter that properly.

I interpret this as *I want only items with `ParentappCategoryId == null` in the first level of my dictionary*.

If that is the case, it should be possible to solve by filtering the app category list *before* iterating through it to add the first-level items to your dictionary.

Here is an example of how that can be achieved using [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) from the System.Linq namespace:

Replace

```csharp
foreach (AppCategoryDataModel category in appCategoryList)
```

with

```csharp
//using System.Linq;

var firstLevelItems = appCategoryList.Where(app => app.ParentappCategoryId == null);

foreach (AppCategoryDataModel category in firstLevelItems)
```

Note: A separate variable is not needed; I would mainly consider using it for readability.

You might as well implement it as follows:

```csharp
//using System.Linq;

foreach (AppCategoryDataModel category in appCategoryList.Where(app => app.ParentappCategoryId == null))
```

---

Also -- I am not sure if this part causes a problem for you, but the logic looks strange to me:

```csharp
SubCategory = category.ParentappCategoryId != null
    ? GetSubCategoryList(appCategoryList, category.AppCategoryId)
    : new List<SecondLevelCategory>()
```

I interpret the code as:

> Populate `category`'s `SubCategory` **only if `category` has a parent**

To me, given your condition for the first-level items of *not having a parent*, this seems to imply that *none of the first-level items should have any sub categories*. I find this to be contradictive. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

If I am right, I'd suggest implementing `GetSubCategoryList()` so that it returns an empty list if none of the items in `appCategoryList` has a `ParentappCategoryId == category.AppCategoryId`.

If you have that, you can simply go with

```csharp
SubCategory = GetSubCategoryList(appCategoryList, category.AppCategoryId)
```

---

##### Update: Possible implementation of `GetSubCategoryList` (`GetSubCategories`)

You mention in your comment that your current implementation of `GetSubCategoryList` (and `GetThirdLevelCategoryList`) pretty much repeats the implementation of your main `foreach` loop.

To my understanding, this indicates that the classes `FirstLevelCategory` and `SecondLevelCategory` (and `ThirdLevelCategory`) could be replaced by a single class: `AppCategory`.

```csharp
public class AppCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProtocolCount { get; set; }
    public List<AppCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
    public List<ProtocolDetails> ProtocolData { get; set; }
}
```

Furthermore, the logic for populating `AppCategoryProtocolData` could be simplified by grouping all the app categories that share `(AppCategory)Id` and creating a list of `ProtocolDetails` based on that grouping.

From here, we can make use of recursion to get the sub categories of each category.

```csharp
private static List<AppCategory> GetSubCategories(
    List<AppCategoryDataModel> appCategories,
    int? parentAppCategoryId)
{
    // return empty list if no sub categories exist
    if (!appCategories.Any(ac => ac.ParentAppCategoryId == parentAppCategoryId))
    {
        return new();
    }
    
    List<AppCategory> subCategories = appCategories
        .Where(ac => ac.ParentAppCategoryId == parentAppCategoryId)
        // Simplify the logic of populating the ProtocolData content
        .GroupBy(ac => ac.AppCategoryId)
        .Select(gr => new AppCategory
            {
                Id = gr.Key,
                Name = gr.First().AppCategoryName,
                ProtocolData = gr
                    .Where(ac => ac.ProtocolId != null)
                    .Select(ac => new ProtocolDetails
                        {
                            Id = ac.ProtocolId.Value,
                            Title = ac.ProtocolTitle 
                        })
                    .ToList()
            })
        .ToList();
    
    foreach (var subCat in subCategories)
    {
        // Make recursive method call to populate _this_ category's sub categories
        subCat.SubCategories = GetSubCategories(appCategories, subCat.Id);
        subCat.ProtocolCount = subCat.ProtocolData.Count;
    }
    
    return subCategories;
}
```

As it turns out, all the first-level items in your dictionary may in fact be considered as being *sub categories of a (non-existing) category with `Id == null`*. We can take advantage of this observation by finding our first-level items using our implementation of `GetSubCategories`.

The main code block may be reduced to:

```csharp
Dictionary<int, AppCategory> dictCategories = new();

var firstLevelCategories = GetSubCategories(appCategoryList, null);

foreach (var category in firstLevelCategories)
{
    dictCategories.Add(category.Id, category);
}
```

The resulting hierarchy, using your example input data, looks as follows:

> Call survival guide
>         ABC: Evaluation
>                 New Category Level-1
>                         New Category Level-2
>                 test
>                         New category3
> Contact information
>         ABC: Evaluation
> ItemHostpital
>         ABC: 3/28/20
>         ABC: Evaluation
>         ABC: section
>         ABC: 3/31/20
> ItemResearch
>         ABC: Evaluation
> OE
>         ABC: Evaluation
>                 mmkk update
>                 xdgdrg
> OEM
> UP
>         ABC: Evaluation

Note that this result includes `OEM`, which is not included in your *expected result*. If you only want first-level items in your dictionary that contain `ProtocolData`, you could e.g. filter as follows:

```
foreach (var category in firstLevelCategories.Where(c => c.ProtocolCount > 0))
{
    dictCategories.Add(category.Id, category);
}
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RXnaII).

Comment: oh! I just missed the where clause. do you have any suggestions on how to implement `GetSubCategoryList`? I have implemented it the same way I have implemented for `FirstLevelCategory` and also called `GetThirdLeveCategoryList`, my code has been repeattive, do you have any suggestion to make it is generic?

Comment: @AkshayKriti I have added a suggestion of how you could implement `GetSubCategoryList()` (I have renamed it to `GetSubCategories()` -- this is not important, just my naming preference) using recursion, and  how you could rewrite and simplify your main code block. Please let me know if it needs better explanation or if it otherwise does not work for you.

Comment: It is indeed a great solution but I have a slightly different implementation of the model you choose here. I am editing my question here.

Comment: I have different fields for the third and second categories, they do not have a similar kind of configuration.

Comment: This question is growing quite a lot. Not sure about the best solution for that, but I have implemented a suggestion [**here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8aNCjF), using an interface for the common properties of all three category classes. (I don't think such an interface is actually needed for that implementation, though.) You can play around with it and see if it may suit your needs. :)

Comment: that answers everything with this question. thank you for your time.